# P4000 and ESX storage design

Tags: raid, storage, replication, lefthand

I need help and advice how to design my volumes to fit the need - good performance for sql type application, no lack of performance for file servers,  remote copy or replication to dr site for protection for 90% data.

my situation - site A ( production )
1. we have 5 esx, 2 P4000 lefthand in each site.
2. we have 2-3 sql server on each esx, around 5 web and 1 file servers. ( this could be rearranged ). total around 30 to 40 virtual servers, total used storage would be around 10TB.
3. there will be some servers where the data protection could be not necessary and no need remote site protection.

site B ( 90% for dr purpose ) - have 5 esx, 2 P4000 lefthand, both sites are linked using a dedicated 1 gig pipe, NOT expecting to have any site to site redundancy or recovery for now, but having a DR solution using remote copy or kind of replication is mandatory.

Need your help to find the best solution for the above situation - thank you all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does lefthand offer any sort of block level replication software?

Have you looked at the VMware Site Recovery Manager?  What you are talking about it what it does.

Comment: I need to know the best way i could create my volumes. for SRM , this is not in the plan for now due to its cost involvement.

thx

Comment: Classify the guests with a recovery goal (5 minutes, 1 days, never) and setup LUNs for each target goal.  Then setup those LUNs to replicate to the other site.

Comment: What type of volume you create for sql type servers ? would you put both os and data in same volume ?
thx

Comment: If the logs and data are on the same volume (as are the system databases) then it doesn't really matter.  If the database is split across different LUNs that's when things start getting a little harder as the LUNs that all make up the databases need to be consistent with each other.  For this to work the array needs to support consistency groups.